# How to input a correct file name in FileReader method in java

Tags: java, filereader

I am working with eclipse and I try to read a HTML file to display it in a web browser (I am doing a http Java server).

I was using `FileReader()` function and it worked fine, then I restarted eclipse and it gave me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: index.html
```

this is how I read the file :

```
String httpContent;

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("index.html"));
                try {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = br.readLine();

                    while (line != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        sb.append("\n");
                        line = br.readLine();
                    }
                    httpContent = sb.toString();
                } finally {
                    br.close();
                }
```

the file "index.html" is on the same level as the java file.

What should I change to get `FileReader` to work again?

Comment: Do you know what relative paths are and what a current/working directory is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know if closing eclips resets some parameters but to solve my problem, I just put the path to my HTML file from the project folder

so : `src/Ex5/index.html` instead of `index.html`